# Django:how to make the dynamic drop down list based on Another app's table

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have two apps, the App1 contains the value "Region"(with duplicate), in App2, I want to base on the distinct "Region" Value to show the drop down list.

**App 1 model.py:**

```
class A(models.Model):
    Region=models.CharField(verbose_name='Region',max_length=10,blank=True)
    ......
```

**App 2 model.py:**

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import dupont

class input(models.Model):
    Region=models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

**APP 2 Forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import input
from dupont.models import A   /*Here I want to import the class from the 1st App
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import Queue

class inputform(forms.ModelForm):
    regionlist = forms.ChoiceField(label=u'Region',choices=())
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
    super(inputform,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
    self.fields['regionlist'].choices=((x.que,x.disr) for x in dupont.objects.values('Region').distinct())    

*/*Above code is to make the dynamic drop down list, based on the 1st App's table, and only use the distinct value from the column "Region", but it seems the query is not correct.
```

Error here shows:'dict' object has no attribute 'que'*

```
class Meta:
    model = input
    fields = ('Region')
```

**App2 html:**

```
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}

    <select name="">
        {% for val,name in form.choice_filed.choices %}
            <option value="{{ val }}" {% ifequal data.val val %}selected {% endifequal %}>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>    /* here is to show the drop down list from app2

    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" />p>div>
</form>
```

The error code at present is :'dict' object has no attribute 'que' to that drop down list code line.

Comment: Why are you doing this? If you want a relationship between two models, you use a ForeignKey. That will automatically give you a select list. (Plus, you need to make your example consistent; is `que` supposed to be the same as `Region`? And what is `disr`?`)

Comment: But I want to have a filter on that column, not to show the same list directly.

Comment: I don't understand why that is relevant. Having a ForeignKey doesn't mean you can't filter on it.

Comment: Filter it how? Where? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: The "Region" in App 1 model is NOT a primary key, there are many duplicates. And there is no 1 to many relationship between App 1's Model and App 2's Model. In this case, I don't think we can use the foreign key in App2 model, correct me if I am wrong please.   What I want to to show in App 2 model only the Distinct "Region" value from App1.

Answer (score 0):

`dupont.objects.values('Region')` returns a [list of dictionaries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#values).

Comment: I delete the x.que,x.disr, change this line to "self.fields['regionlist'].choices=(dupont.objects.values('Region').distinct())", but it still let the error of "'inputform' object has no attribute 'get". Really don't know why .thanks for your suggestion.